# class undefined C++

Tags: c++, oop

In test i am trying to create object partTimeEmployee, but i get an undefined reference error, and i don't understand why? I dont understand the error because i pass it the right kind of data. is my .cpp and .h not included right?

test.cpp: (.text+0xb7): undefined reference to 'partTimeEmployee(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'

work.h

```
#ifndef WORK_H
#define WORK_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>

class work{
        public:
          void DisplayMe();
          work(string x,string y);
          work();
          ~work();

        string name;
        string id;
};
#endif
```

work.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include "work.h"

using namespace std;

work::work(){
        cout<<name<<"in default work constructor"<<endl;
}

work::~work(){
        cout<< name << " calling work destructor. " << endl;
}

work::work(string x, string y){

        name = x;
        id = y;

        cout << "in parent constructor" <<endl;
}

void work::DisplayMe(){
        cout << "NAME: " << name << "    ID#: " << id <<endl;
}
```

Employee.h

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

include "work.h"
using namespace std;

class Employee : public sfasu{

        public:
          Employee();
          Employee(string x);
          ~Employee();

        string department;

};
#endif
```

Employee.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include "Employee.h"

using namespace std;

Employee::Employee(){
        cout<<name<<"in default sfasu constructor"<<endl;
}

Employee::~Employee(){
        cout<< name << " calling parent destructor. " << endl;
}

Employee::Employee(string x){

        department = x;

        cout << "in parent constructor" <<endl;
}
```

partTimeEmployee.h

```
#ifndef PARTTIMEEMPLOYEE_H
#define PARTTIMEEMPLOYEE_H

#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

class partTimeEmployee : public Employee{

        public:
          partTimeEmployee();
          partTimeEmployee(string x);
          ~partTimeEmployee();

        string hourly_wage;

};
#endif
```

partTimeEmployee.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include "partTimeEmployee.h"

using namespace std;

partTimeEmployee::partTimeEmployee(){
        cout<<"in default partTimeEmployee constructor"<<endl;
}

partTimeEmployee::~partTimeEmployee(){
        cout<< " calling FTP destructor. " << endl;
}

partTimeEmployee::partTimeEmployee(string x){

        hourly_wage = x;

        cout << "partTimeEmployeeconstructor" <<endl;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "sfasu.h"
#include "Employee.h"
#include "partTimeEmployee.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

partTimeEmployee one("data");
}
```

Comment: `class partTimeEmployee : public partTimeEmployee` looks viciously recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build application you first compile source files (usually .cpp) to object files (usually .o or .obj) and then link them together into executable. It can be done explicitly through command line, using makefile or such or IDE. Your error shows that object file from compilation of partTimeEmployee.cpp is not included in linking. You do not provide enough information how you build your executable so it is difficult to say how to fix it.

Comment: when i compile test shouldn't everything compile since, everything is included?

Comment: @johnwayne no, you include headers, source files compiled separately and then have to be linked together. Read this for example http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~jestes/howto/g++compiling.txt

Comment: It depends...if you do it from an IDE, the IDE will usually do that for you but if you compile (actually is link) it from command line, you must specify all objects to g++ (based on the error message I concluded you're on Linux): `g++ -o test $(SOME_OTHER_FLAGS) test.o partTimeEmployee.o Employee.o work.o`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
class partTimeEmployee : public partTimeEmployee
```

to

```
class partTimeEmployee : public Employee
```